# Stretching column width to fill all the available space in GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-gridlayout

[image: GridLayout of two rows and three columns]

Above is the image of my design but it is not as desired, I want few editing in this grid and those editing are are as follow:

1. How to stretch the `TextView_1` and fill the available space on its left and right?
2. In Row_0 * column_0 (ImageView), I used rowSpan = "2" and minHight*minWidth = "64dp", now why I have to define the height of the `TextView_1` and `TextView_2 & 3` externally i.e. 32dp (Half of the height of ImageView) for both rows, I want theirs height to be stretched equally according to ImageView?
3. How to set the text alignment center_horizontally && center_vertically in the cell?

Here is My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/row_image"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        android:minHeight="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="34"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:id="@+id/row_price"
        android:minHeight="32dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="66"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/row_disc"
        android:minHeight="32dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

remove from textview row 0 col 1

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

and add to textview row 0 col 1
           textview row 1 col 1
           textview row 1 col 2

```
 android:gravity="center"
 android:textAlignment="center"
```

should be look like this

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/row_image"
        android:minHeight="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="70"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="TextView_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:id="@+id/row_name"
        android:minHeight="32dp"
      />



    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="TextView_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="34"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:id="@+id/row_price"
        android:minHeight="32dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="TextView_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="66"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/row_disc"
        android:minHeight="32dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

columnweight work like this [image]

Comment: It is working fine but I didn't get that why any number of weight is working in ' android:layout_columnWeight="70"' not only 70, even when I write '1' it's working.

Comment: u can set android:layout_columnWeight="1" actually compare it with other column if available there is no other column at that row show you can given any value but when you change it in row 1 you can understand

Comment: One more trouble I fall in this design that it is appearing same in the design as intended but when I am using this Layout in 'ListView's' row, aligning is not working, all the 'TextView's are left alligned no matter I used [CODE] android:gravity="center" android:textAlignment="center" [/CODE].

Comment: check the image http://mbedded.in/randoms/scr_01.png and code is the same as you suggested.